# How to get current URL?

Tags: javascript, php, html

For example:

```
when I visit http://mywebsite.com/howtoloseweight/, click "part 1" link, I will be redirected to http://mywebsite.com/howtoloseweight/1

 when I visit http://mywebsite.com/howtoloseweightfast/, click "part 1" link, I will be redirected to http://mywebsite.com/howtoloseweightfast/1
```

How to do that ? Thanks !

Comment: Did you check the **Related** section to your right ? ----->

Comment: Do you want this done in javascript or php?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript:

```
window.location
```

See the link below for more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 steps:

1. open your text editor and put thest lines in it

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteRule ^howtoloseweight/1$ /howtoloseweight/1.html [L]
2. save file as ".htaccess"
3. make a link `<a href="/howtoloseweight/1">part 1</a>`. Doing this the link will go to `http://mywebsite.com/howtoloseweight/1` as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

on the part 1 link of your first page (http://mywebsite.com/howtoloseweight) make the link as below

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/howtoloseweight/1">part 1</a>
```

or

```
<a href="./1">part 1</a>
```

on the second page (http://mywebsite.com/howtoloseweightfast/) make the link as below

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/howtoloseweightfast/1">part 1</a>
```

or

```
<a href="./1">part 1</a>
```

**FYI**:- "." always refers the current location.

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if(isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"])){if (($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
echo curPageURL();
?>
```